# How to pass a variable in web api url

Tags: javascript

I am making a web API application and i am facing a problem .Problem is that i want pass the variable in the URL of web API by which i can make my URL dynamic.Please help me my code is given below

```
 $('.srtMenu').click(function () {
                var shortStar = $(this).text();
                var starValue;
                if(shortStar=='Bad')
                {
                    star = '1';
                }
                $.getJSON("/api/tblProducts/Prd101/{star}/allReview", function (data) {
                    var dataCount = data.length;
                    var dataLimit = Number(dataCount);


                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        var star = "*";
                        var starValue = val.Rating;
                        var starLimit = Number(starValue);
                        for (i = 1; i < starLimit; i++) {
                            star = star + "*";

                        }
                        $('<tr><td><span id="star">' + star + '</span></td><td><p id="CustReview" >' + val.Review + '</p><p id="CustName">' + val.UserName + '</p><span id="webName"> make an oreder.com</span>,<span id="webName">Certified customer</span><br><span id="reviewDate"><br>' + val.Date + '</span></td></tr>').appendTo("#tblReviewDetails");

                    });

                });


            });
```

In the code  `$.getJSON("/api/tblProducts/Prd101/{star}/allReview" this is the url and` i want to make star value dynamic by which i could give input from variable star
Please help me i am needy

Comment: This question seems to be about how to do string concatenation in JavaScript and does not appear to have anything to do with ASP. Please clarify.

Comment: Change `"/api/tblProducts/Prd101/{star}/allReview"` to `"/api/tblProducts/Prd101/" + star + "/allReview"` - though as Blurp mentions, this has nothing to do with Web APi - looks like you have lifted the route template right out of an api controller.

Comment: Thanks for reply i do that and find my output

Answer (score 1):

```
`/api/tblProducts/Prd101/${star}/allReview`
```

You can use Template Literals.
Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to learn more and scroll down to 'Expression interpolation'

NOTE: This uses back ticks. Not quotes.

Comment: thanks for your answer by the way i solve my problem its so simple just used +" "+ for adding variable

Comment: @AkshayTomar Using + (string concatenation) can get messy if you have a long template. It's also not as readable in my opinion. Template literal is a new feature is ES6.

Comment: ohh ,thanks for telling me new feature i can understand what you trying to say